# Flutter: Button should output an widget but doesn't

Tags: flutter

This is my function:

```
Widget RandomSkill(Widget SkillJonglieren) {
  return Widget SkillJonglieren;
```

This is the stateless Widget "SkillJonglierten"

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Jonglieren'),
            Image.asset('images/Jonglieren.jpg')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the button

```
body: Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: RandomSkill,
        child: Text('Zufälliger Skill')
      ),
    ));
```

I just want, that when i press the button that this widget is shown

Answer (score 0):

You need a `StatefulWidget`. In its `State` class, you need to remember whether the `SkillJonglierten` is shown or not. If it's shown, you need to show it in your `build()` function. Otherwise, you should not show it in your `build()` function. So, this becomes: https://codepen.io/gazialankus/pen/rNxgBgx

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isShown;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Show'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isShown = true;
                });
              }
            ), 
            if (isShown == true) SkillJonglieren()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! What do i have to do, when i want to align the button in the center bottom?

Comment: change this line `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`. I did it in the codepen.

Comment: yes, but i want the widget wich is shown when the button is pressed, that it is in the Center or Begin of the body :)